# VBA compile error: "Sub or Function not defined"

Tags: excel, vba

The following is my code and I am getting the compile error while it runs. Please help me to solve.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim yourname As String
    Dim yourbirthday As Date
    Dim yourincome As Currency
    your Name = "Rahul"
    yourbirthday = "26/03/1996"
    yourincome = "100000"
    Range("A1") = yourname
    Range("A2") = yourbirthday
    Range("A3") = yourincome
End Sub
```

Comment: I assume the error is highlighting the line `your Name = "Rahul"`.  What looks wrong in that statement?  (Think about why the "N" in "Name" is in uppercase.  Why isn't it in uppercase elsewhere?  What is different between the variable names in those instances?)

Answer (score 0):

There is a space between "your" and "Name" in:

```
your Name = "Rahul"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
your Name = "Rahul"
```

Should be:

```
yourname = "Rahul"
```